# Convergence in measure of sequence $f_n(x)=|\sin(a_n x+b_n)|^{p_n}$ with $p_n\rightarrow\infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

This is a problem from a set of old Analysis qualifying exams I am using to prepare for my upcoming graduate qualifying test.

Suppose $a_n$, $b_n$ and $p_n$ are numerical sequences such that, $a_n>0$, $\liminf_na_n>0$, $p_n\geq0$ and $\lim_\limits{n \to \infty}p_n=\infty$. Define the sequence of functions
$$f_n(x)=|\sin(a_n x+b_n)|^{p_n}, \quad x\in[0,2\pi].$$
Show that $f_n$ converges to $0$ in measure. Here, the measure space is $[0,2\pi]$ with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and the Lebesgue measure.

If the $a_n$ were integers, the problem simplifies considerably since $f_n$ and $f(x)=\sin x$ have the same distribution (as random variables over the normalized Lebesgue measure on $[0,2\pi]$) which can be check easily: $f$ has period $2\pi$, hence
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{2\pi}_0 \mathbf{1}_E(\sin_n(a_nx+b_n))\,dx=\frac{1}{2\pi a_n}\int^{a_n2\pi+b_n}_{b_n}\mathbf{1}_E(\sin(x))\,dx=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{2\pi}_0\mathbf{1}_E(\sin(x))\,dx$$
for any measurable set $E\subset[0,2\pi]$.
I am having a but of a struggle to carry on with a similar argument for $A_n$ not integer.

I will appreciate any help, hint or a solution to this. Thank you!

**Edit:** This is a two part problem. I just wrote down the first part, and perhaps the easiest part, of the problem. The second part asks whether convergence in probability can be *improved* to convergence point wise almost surely for $f_n$. I may post the second part in a different posting later in case I don't get too far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of estimating the measure of the sets $E_n(\varepsilon)=\{x\in[0,2\pi]: |f_n(x)|>\varepsilon\}$ directly (as I think the OP is suggesting), it is much easier to show that
$\int^{2\pi}_0|f_n|\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$.
The condition $\liminf_na_n>0$ implies that there is $a>0$ such that $a_n>a$ for all $n$ large enough. The periodicity of $\sin$ implies that
$$m(|f_n|>\varepsilon]\leq\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\int^{2\pi}_0|f_n|\leq\frac{1}{\varepsilon a_n}\int^{2\pi\lceil a_n\rceil + b_n}_{b_n}|\sin x|^{p_n}\, dx=\frac{\lceil a_n\rceil}{\varepsilon a_n}\int^{2\pi}_0|\sin x|^{p_n}\,dx
$$
where $x\mapsto\lceil x\rceil$ is the ceiling function. The factor $\frac{\lceil a_n\rceil}{a_n}$ is bounded above since $a_n>a$ for all $n\geq N$. The conclusion follows by dominated convergence.

---

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint: when $a_n$ is not integer, you can just extend $[0,2\pi]$ to contain an integer number of periods of $\sin(a_n x + b_n)$ and look at the measure of the points in the extended set where
where $|\sin(a_n x + b_n)|^{p_n} > \epsilon$ and show this goes to zero. By the periodicity of $\sin$ it's the same for all values of $b_n$. The condition that $\liminf_n a_n $ is nonzero is there to ensure the functions don't "spread out" faster than the increasing $p_n$ can "tamp down" the graphs.

Comment: (+1) Thanks! That is what my professor suggested but I could not get too far. Perhaps you can provide a few more details.

Comment: The measure where $|\sin(a_nx + b_n)^{p_n}| > \epsilon$ is the same as the measure where $|\sin(a_n x + b_n)| > \epsilon^{1 \over p_n}$. Since the $p_n$ go to infinity, this becomes an ever smaller portion of the domain as $n \rightarrow \infty$, near the points where $\sin(a_nx + b_n) = \pm1$.